# What happens if I put a stolen item on my follower and get arrested on Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can followers be used to keep stolen items from “the law”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42149/can-followers-be-used-to-keep-stolen-items-from-the-law)

I'm asking this because I started a new game to get stuff done that I didn't do before and I'm about to join the thieves' guild. For the starting quest I remember getting pinched for stealing something. I finished the quest for the Golden Claw and stole it back but I don't have anywhere to stash it.

To stop it from getting taken when I get arrested, I was wondering if I could leave it on my follower and have it not be taken?

Comment: When paying your fine and jail, it only affects your inventory, not the followers, even if he/she has an item that belongs to you.